# A proxy ignores the authentication header only for httpS request

Tags: java, https, proxy

I want to send 2 kinds of request via proxy: http and https. Here's how I'm doing an HTTP request:

```
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

and HTTPS:

```
  HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

The rest of the code is **identical**:

```
//..................
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("ip", 1234));

//..................
conn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", auth);
conn.setDoInput(true);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
System.out.println("\n");
```

In case of HTTP it returns 200 and the body of the response which means everything is working fine. However, for HTTPS **requests** it returns:

```
Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

How come?

I don't consider using the class `Authenticator` or `System.setProperty`. I want to figure out why my code isn't working correctly for https and is for http.

Answer (score 0):

You use Basic authentication schema.
According Oracle update # [8u111](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html)

> In some environments, certain authentication schemes may be
>   undesirable when proxying HTTPS. Accordingly, the Basic authentication
>   scheme has been deactivated, by default, in the Oracle Java Runtime,
>   by adding Basic to the jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes
>   networking property.

Thus you need clear list of disabledSchemes by
- or invoke at main static method `System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");`
- or add JVM parameter `-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=`
- or use Apache Common HttpClient